# Running an example pod on Kubernetes with Nvidia GPU nodes

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to setup Kubernetes with Nvidia GPU nodes/slaves.
I followed the guide at https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/kubernetes-install-guide/index.html and I was able to get the node join the cluster. I tried the below kubeadm example pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gpu-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: cuda-container
      image: nvidia/cuda:9.0-base
      command: ["sleep"]
      args: ["100000"]
      extendedResourceRequests: ["nvidia-gpu"]
  extendedResources:
    - name: "nvidia-gpu"
      resources:
        limits:
          nvidia.com/gpu: 1
      affinity:
        required:
          - key: "nvidia.com/gpu-memory"
            operator: "Gt"
            values: ["8000"]
```

The pod fails scheduling & the kubectl events shows:

```
4s          2m           14        gpu-pod.15487ec0ea0a1882        Pod                                          Warning   FailedScheduling        default-scheduler            0/2 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu, 1 PodToleratesNodeTaints.
```

I'm using AWS EC2 instances. m5.large for the master node & g2.8xlarge for the slave node. Describing the node also gives "**nvidia.com/gpu:  4**".
Can anybody help me out if I'm missing any steps/configurations?

Comment: Could you share results of a command for your nvidia workers: `kubectl describe nodes`. And also share results of commands: `kubectl describe pods gpu-pod` and `kubectl logs gpu-pod`. Information you provided is not enough to understand what is happening.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Adding a Google docs links with the requested logs:
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U9ai7N3m_uDeQH4Qhd0m38G4RHSCNpHsw9x1AqyDGP4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like you don't have enough resources for scheduling the the pod, try to decrease amount of required `nvidia.com/gpu-memory` memory or expand resources of Nvidia GPU nodes

Comment: The pod is requesting 8 GB memory whereas a g2.8xlarge instance has 60 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AWS G2 [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-g2-instance-type-with-4x-more-gpu-power/), `g2.8xlarge` servers have the following resources:

- Four NVIDIA GRID GPUs, each with 1,536 CUDA cores and 4 GB of video
  memory and the ability to encode either four real-time HD video
  streams at 1080p or eight real-time HD video streams at 720P.
- 32 vCPUs.
- 60 GiB of memory.
- 240 GB (2 x 120) of SSD storage.

Looking at the comments, 60 GB is standard RAM, and it is used for regular calculations. `g2.8xlarge` servers have 4 GPUs with 4 GB of GPU memory each, and this memory is used for calculations in `nvidia/cuda` containers.

In your case, it is requested 8 GB of GPU memory per GPU, but your server has only 4 GB. Therefore, the cluster experiences a lack of resources for scheduling the POD. So, try to reduce the memory usage in the Pod settings or try to use a server with a larger amount of GPU memory.